# Mutating copy of string and returning value instead of changing original string

Tags: c++, string, recursion, constants

I have a recursive function which uses string and the operation i perform are

```
erase, replace, insert,..

int method(original_string):
    ...
    min(operation1(original_string), operation2(original_string)) 
    ...
```

I want to keep the original string unchanged but rather need a mutated new string

```
mutate(original_string, operation) :
        temp = copyof(original_string)
        operation(temp);
        return temp;
```

Because the problem is operation1 affects original_string and i want the real original_string for operation2 too.

But this is not possible for different functions, i need to write for each and every function.

- In C++ is something exists already or workaround possible to achieve this?
- I feel like defining string argument as const * original_string and expecting the operations to behave likewise.

Comment: _"I feel like defining string argument as `const * original_string `"_ That's probably the best idea. But you should consider to use a `const std::string&` reference parameter, rather than a pointer.

Comment: Why don't you use copyof in the min function call? :  min(operation1( copyof(original_string)), operation2(copyof(original_string))) ?

Comment: yeah, sorry i meant const string, but this stops any operation on the original string as far as i know !!!

Comment: copy in c++ is possible like temp = original_string; so my code 'll become messy like : temp=orig_s; v1 = method(op1(orig_s))); temp=orig_s; v2 = method(op2(orig_s)),... min(v1,v2) .. i want to avoid that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have defined a clone function

```
string clone(string orig_str) {
    string cloned_str(orig_str);
    return cloned_str;
}
```

and in the method class calling the function

```
min(
    method(clone(original_string).erase(...)), 
    method(clone(original_string).replace(...)
    )
```

also changed the method parameters to

```
method(const orignal_string) { ... }
```

Thanks @Scooter for the input.